How to Enable "Copy on Selection" in Visual Studio Code?
I'm looking to improve my workflow in Visual Studio Code by enabling the "Copy on Selection" feature. This feature would automatically copy any text I select to the clipboard without requiring an explicit copy command (Ctrl+C).

Is this what you are looking for? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dinhani.copy-on-select

@JayBuckman The problem with this extension is that it only copies on selection using the mouse, but when I use keyboard shortcuts to select (which is most of the time), it doesn't copy.

Not exactly what you're looking for- but If you're on Linux, the default value of the editor.selectionClipboard setting enables pasting the currently selected text with the middle mouse button to where you click, or pressing shift+insert (see issue ticket #91051).
I don't know about the other platforms though.
